# Multiplication table for a frieze group.

Tags: group-theory, rotations

I am doing the following question:

[image]

I wrote the formulae for $T_n$ as $(x+2n, y)$. I'm not sure about the forumlae for $R_n$ though. I think it will be $(something,-y)$ but I am unsure about the x component here.

Also, when computing the multiplication table, is the following correct?

$T_n$
$T_n$ gives $T_{2n}$.

$R_nR_n$ gives $I$.

I am unsure what $T_nR_n$ and $R_nT_n$ would give however. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I might be misunderstanding but I believe it would be $T_0$ as this would shift it by 0 periods to the right. It also aligns with the formula if n=0 it would be (x,y).

Comment: True! $T_0$ is your $I$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin This question sounds silly but how can I use that knowledge now that I know $T_0$ is $I$ to form my multiplication table if there is no I in the table?

Comment: Knowing your $I$ is important enough in its own right. Also, now you may readily tell which element is the inverse of $T_n$ (which may not be needed for the multiplication table, but is a part of really knowing the group).

Comment: A request from your friendly moderator. When you are done with the comment exchange could you please purge it a bit. A possibility is that one of you posts a summary as an answer, and then you can delete all of them (and flag mine for deletion also). A system flag has been raised for the sheer number of comments :-)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{array}{ccc} & T_n & R_n \\ T_m & T_{m+n} & R_{m+n} \\ R_m & R_{m-n} & T_{m-n} \\ \end{array}

Comment: Good. Now add the dividing lines to the table, which I forgot to tell you about. Change {ccc} to {c|c|c}, and add a \hline after each \\. Then add some words to the effect that you know what is the identity element and what is the inverse of every element. Then remove most of your comments (say, all but the first three), because the long beard of comments irates the moderators. I'll remove mine as well.